# Microservice multiplies postgres connections

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a service wrote via golang, which work as a consumer, It gets data from kafka's queue and stores it in PostgreSQL database. While doing certain request golang starts to multiply PG connections and then exceeds the limit of them. I don't know why, please help me with this issue.
Here is the code:

```
func SaveMessageStatus(msg models.Message) error {

db := GetPostgreInstance() // Get *sql.DB instance

// Проверяем есть ли записи

rows, err := db.Query(`select * from "tNotifStatus" where "NotificationId" = $1`, msg.NotificationID)

if err != nil {
    CheckError(err, "SLCT status", "")
    return err
}

if rows.Next() {
    // Смотрим если запись в таблице уже есть, тогда просто обновляем статусы по сообщению
    fsql := `update "tNotifStatus" set "Status" = $1, "Error" = $2, "UpdateTime" = $3 where "NotificationId" = $4`

    _, err = db.Exec(fsql, msg.Status, msg.Error, msg.UpdateTime, msg.NotificationID)

    if err != nil {
        //Логируем
        CheckError(err, "UPDT status", "")
        return err
    }

} else {
    // Если записей нет, то создаем новую
    fsql := `insert into "tNotifStatus" values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5)`
    _, err = db.Exec(fsql, msg.NotificationID, msg.Status, msg.Error, msg.ChannelName, msg.UpdateTime)
    if err != nil {
        //Логируем
        CheckError(err, "INS status", "")
        return err
    }
}
return err
```

}

If we see PG admin monitoring, we have a lot of new connections:

6460    UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:35:14 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46462   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:35:17 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46463   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:35:17 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46517   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:20 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46518   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:21 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46520   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:22 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46521   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:23 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46522   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:23 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46524   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:24 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46525   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:24 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46527   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:25 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46529   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:25 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46531   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:26 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46532   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:26 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead
46534   UCS ucs     10.3.40.20  2018-12-27 09:36:27 +06 idle    Client: ClientRead

They all try to execute

```
select * from "tNotifStatus" where "NotificationId" = $1
```

May be it is related with Wait Event (ClientRead), golang lib starts new connection while the old one is still trying to finish "SELECT"

Here is code of connection to DB

```
    func GetPostgreInstance() *sql.DB {
    return postgreClient
}

func InitPqConnection() {

    var err error

    var configuration models.Configuration
    configuration.Load()

    connStr := configuration.PostgreConnString

    postgreClient, err = sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        CheckError(err, "Connection to db", "")
        panic("Error connection to DB")
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to db")
}
```

Comment: I think you need a defer on your db

Comment: @morissette you mean defer close? My service works as a worker constantly, so it is not necessary to close it with defer.

Comment: You need to close `rows`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either use `QueryRow()`, since you aren't using nor expecting multiple rows, or do a `defer rows.Close()` (which you should *always* do when using `.Query`

https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close

> Close closes the Rows, preventing further enumeration. If Next is called and returns false and there are no further result sets, the Rows are closed automatically and it will suffice to check the result of Err. Close is idempotent and does not affect the result of Err.

http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

> If for some reason you exit that loop – an early return, or so on – then the rows doesn’t get closed, and the connection remains open.

```
rows, err := db.Query(`select * from "tNotifStatus" where "NotificationId" = $1`, msg.NotificationID)
if err != nil {
    CheckError(err, "SLCT status", "")
    return err
}
defer rows.Close()
```

Since you are not even iterating over `rows.Next()` you are basically never hitting the automatic close condition, and always leaving your connections open.